# Server sends json data correctly. Client parses it wrong

Tags: android, json

I have a PHP code that generates a JSON string to send to my Android app. This part works.
The problem is when my app captures that string and try to convert it into a JSONArray object.
The main idea is to store that data inside a SQLite database.

Here's the code that captures the JSON string:

```
public void getPostResponse(){
    try{
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is,"iso-8859-1"),8);
        sb = new StringBuilder();
        line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line+"\n");
        }
        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();
        Log.e("getPostResponse","result= "+sb.toString());
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag","Error converting result "+e.toString());
    }
}
```

And this is the result in the LogCat:

```
10-11 16:27:01.171: E/getPostResponse(9155): result= [{ "establecimientos":[]},{ "rutas":[]},{ "formularios":[]},{ "clientes":[]},{ "mediciones":[]}]
```

This is why I think there's an error, the result variable should contain the whole JSON string and it doesn't. Any ideas?

Variables br, sb, line and result are declared globally.
JSON sent from server is already a JSONArray (starts with '[' and ends with ']'), is this what's causing the problem?

This is the json string:

```
[
    {
        "establecimientos": [
            {
                "idestablecimiento": "108",
                "nombre": "Establecimiento 123",
                "direccion": "632-8165 Non Road",
                "idruta": "104",
                "idempresa": "1004"
            },
            {
                "idestablecimiento": "102",
                "nombre": "Establecimiento XYZ",
                "direccion": "Ap #124-9882 Risus, Street",
                "idruta": "106",
                "idempresa": "1006"
            },
            {
                "idestablecimiento": "106",
                "nombre": "Unicasa La Candelaria",
                "direccion": "P.O. Box 898, 6831 Morbi Rd.",
                "idruta": "106",
                "idempresa": "1001"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "rutas": [
            {
                "idruta": "106",
                "nombre": "Petare"
            },
            {
                "idruta": "104",
                "nombre": "La Castellana"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "formularios": [
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "nombre": "Encuesta Libre",
                "idestablecimiento": "108"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "nombre": "Encuesta Libre",
                "idestablecimiento": "102"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "nombre": "Encuesta Libre",
                "idestablecimiento": "106"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "clientes": [
            {
                "idcliente": "1002",
                "nombre": "Sibelius",
                "idempresa": "1006"
            },
            {
                "idcliente": "1009",
                "nombre": "Lavasoft",
                "idempresa": "1004"
            },
            {
                "idcliente": "1000",
                "nombre": "Cakewalk",
                "idempresa": "1001"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "mediciones": [
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "100",
                "texto": "1) FALTA DE PRODUCTO",
                "tipopregunta": "Seleccion Simple",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "101",
                "texto": "2) PRE VENDEDOR NO VISITA",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "102",
                "texto": "3) ENTREGADOR NO DESPACHA",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "103",
                "texto": "4) NEVERA FUERA DE SERVICIO",
                "tipopregunta": "Seleccion Simple",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "104",
                "texto": "5) NEVERA CONTAMINADA",
                "tipopregunta": "Seleccion Simple",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "105",
                "texto": "6) CLIENTE EXCLUSIVO DE LA COMPETENCIA",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "106",
                "texto": "7) FALTA DE MATERIAL POP EN PDV",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "107",
                "texto": "8) CLIENTE CERRADO",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "108",
                "texto": "9) NEGACIÓN POR PARTE DEL CLIENTE",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "109",
                "texto": "10) PRODUCTO VENCIDO",
                "tipopregunta": "Seleccion Simple",
                "tipodato": "String"
            },
            {
                "idformulario": "100",
                "idmedicion": "110",
                "texto": "11) PROMOCIONES ESPECIALES",
                "tipopregunta": "Si o No",
                "tipodato": "String"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Variable is (InputStream) should contain the data sent from the server... Conversion to JSONArray occurs in another void of my app, but since variable result doesn't have the data per se... it wont work, despite there's no errors...

Comment: Could you please include the json string? It's hard to tell what's wrong.

Comment: there, i put the json string...

Answer (score 0):

Is more easy get the HttpResponse of your post call, get the entity string and so, create a new JSONObject:

```
//create an Uri
URI uri = new URI(string);
//or using URIUtils

HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(uri);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
```

And so, you can manipulate and inspect the json object. Example, how to get a JSONArray:

```
JSONArray array = json.getJSONArray("estabelecimentos");
```

[]s
Neto